# When spraying anti bacterial agent into the Ac, do you need to remove your pollen filter?

Tags: hvac

The pollen filter maybe at front of or behind blower motor. I have been watching videos on clearing ac smells and some show that you should remove the pollen filter and spray directly onto the blue wer motor which would then spray it on the evaporator.  Is this required or will just spraying in vents be enough with fan on?

If you remove the pollen filter and spray on blower motor with fan on , any dirt/leaves higher up in the system might get sucked into the system and so that be a problem? Mine was under a tree for a while.

Answer (score 1):

Spraying an antibacterial into the system will help a bit, but it's not the best way to correct the problem. But to answer your question, yes, remove the pollen filter first.

Comment: what about leaves getting pulled past the system, wont that be an issue? Mine has alot of leaves in the system and before the filter which are difficult to clean.